# General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 61 in Linux when I build an android app

Tags: java, android, gradle, pyqt, pyqtdeploy

I'm making an android app by using pyqtdeploy in Linux.

I'm using java 17 and gradle 7.1.1 and androidpyqtdeploy occurs this error.

```
General error during conversion: Unsupported class file major version 61
  
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 61
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:189)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:170)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:156)
        at groovyjarjarasm.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:277)
```

I tried with this (https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/13481)
But error is same:(
How can I solve it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NativeScript Android Build fails with an exception - Unsupported class file major version 57](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59573626/nativescript-android-build-fails-with-an-exception-unsupported-class-file-majo)

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error, it helped me to downgrade the Java version to 11 and add this to build.gradle

```
compileJava {
    options.release = 16
}

java {
    toolchain {
        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(16)
    }
}
```